# Date object setting

Tags: date, long-integer

I have a method I have to use to set a Date object, shown in below:

- methodName(Date d)

Now the constructor which takes a long seems a little tricky to handle, 
so I want to hear from you if someone out there knows how to make it function,
that will specify both Year, Month & also Day time.????

Answer (score 1):

You can use [calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instead. It has date and time.

```
Calendar field access

Field                    Explanation
Calendar.YEAR            Identifies the year
Calendar.MONTH           Identifies the month
Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH    Identifies the day
Calendar.HOUR            Identifies the hour
Calendar.MINUTE          Identifies the minute
Calendar.SECOND          Identifies the second
```